# How to Convert Decimal coordinates to structured Coordinates in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Hey there guys im working on a project for school and in the project it requires the user the enter decimal coordinates and convert it into structured format, ie:

> 17.428333°  -->   17° 25' 42"

Does anyone possibly know how to do this? Also the program should be able to do it the opposite way; enter structured coordinates `17° 25' 42"` and covert to decimal coordinates `17.4283333`.

I have got the basic maths used for the converting.  To convert from structured coordinates to decimal coordinates you can use the following :

> 17+25/60+42/3600

and to covert from decimal to structured takes first value `17` as the degrees then to work out the minutes

> 17.4285-17=0.4285*60=25.71

gets rid of the decimal or rounds the decimal to get the minutes, then to work out the seconds

> 25.71-25=0.71*60=42.6

either rounds the decimal or gets rid of the decimal for seconds.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  You seem to know how to do the conversion.  What's the problem?

Comment: You have the algorithm, now just write it in Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you start with a coord in a floating point variable `x`. Calculate degrees, minutes and seconds like this:

```
Degrees := Trunc(x);
x := (x - Degrees)*60;
Minutes := Trunc(x);
x := (x - Minutes)*60
Seconds := Round(x);
```

The opposite direction is simpler. The expression you need is:

```
Degrees + Minutes/60 + Seconds/3600
```

Comment: Thank you for this but how would one go about assigning a user entered value to the floating point variable? sorry for my stupidy still very new to this language

Comment: You place a TEdit on your form and a button and when the user clicks the button you do F := TryStrToFloat(Edit1.Text) http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_TryStrToFloat@string@Double.html

Comment: @Stew22   StrToFloat function and modifications